# BigQuery: select rows where column value contains string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to know how to know how to filter a table by a specific column, when this column contains a specific subtring.

Here's an example of my table:

[image]

I would like to obtain those rows where the column `tsBegin` contains `2020-08-04`, maybe with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
where '2020-08-04' in tsBegin
```

Comment: Your column looks like a `timestamp`, not a string.  You don't want to perform string operations on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date operations:

```
where date(tsBegin) = date '2020-08-04'
```

A column named `tsBegin` should not be a string column, so you just want the date.

If `tsBegin` *is* a string, I would suggest that you convert it to a `timestamp`.

Comment: Yes, it's a timestamp, but still your answer is working and filtering it when I use a substring :)

Answer (score 0):

Use date functions, and half-open intervals:

```
select * 
from mytable
where tsbegin >= date '2020-08-04'
  and tsbegin < date_add(date '2020-08-04', interval 1 day)
```

Although a bit lenghtier to type, direct filtering against literal values is usually much faster than applying a date function on the column being filtered, as in `where date(tsbegin) = date '2020-08-04'`